# Android.How to use other application data?

Tags: android

how to use data from another application to my application in android?
Is there any way to access data from other application in android?

Comment: Please explain what 'data' or what you already tried.

Comment: can u explain which type of data ?

Comment: You can always use startActivityForResult(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)) for result, however the "other application" has to support sending you data back!

Comment: If u want use data from one application to another ,store application1 data in file and access that file from application2.

Comment: You can use files in shared folders.

You can use sockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268320/how-to-implement-an-http-server-on-android

Answer (score 2):

You should read about [sending and receiving content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html) between applications, about [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and return here with better question.

Answer (score 1):

In this Example Calling a Camera Application using Intent, getting Bitmap and set in ImageView.

```
startCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(cameraActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera cancelled by user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```