# How to implement a HTTP Server in android which can be access by other device with browser?

Tags: android

I have a new requirement to implement a HTTP Server which run in a android device. And this HTTP server is access by other device such as PC with browser. I find a example like it: PAW server for android. But I don't know how to implement it. The PAW server for android is very complicate. Is there any simple way to implement this requirement? I also read this article: [How to implement an HTTP server on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268320/how-to-implement-an-http-server-on-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create http server android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329468/create-http-server-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try NanoHttpd. It's only one source file, and you just need to extend it to implement your own requirements.

```
http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/
```